# How to generate a dynamic layout in a new window using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to generate a dynamic layout using jquery. The idea is to have the user select a width and height which will then be used to set the number of images into corresponding rows and columns.

The end result I am looking for is the user to select a grid dimension (3x2 for example) and then have a new window with images filling the space of the grid. I think I am on the right track but I haven't been able to figure out where I am going wrong.

```
var ht = 150 * $("#mapht").val();
var wt = 150 * $("#mapwd").val();
var newwindow;

function openwindow() {
  var wt = 150 * $("#mapwd").val();
  var ht = 150 * $("#mapht").val();
  newwindow = window.open("", "", "top=200,left=200");
  for (i = 1; i < $('#mapht').val(); i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < $('#mapwd').val(); j++) {
      newwindow.document.write("<div class='col" + j + " row" + i + "'></div>");
    }
  }
  newwindow.resizeTo(ht, wt);
  newwindow.focus();
}
$('.testing').click(openwindow);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kishkuman13/ggwsgbq8/16/

Comment: You have given wrong id for both height and width textbox in jsfiddle, First update that

Comment: @HidaytRahman, the ids are correct. I fixed it via the solution listed below.

Comment: oops my mistake it was swapped

Answer (score 0):

You made the following mistake:

Here, `for (i = 1; i < $('#mapht').val(); i++) {`. On the UI the default value is 1 and your for loop start from `i = 1` so the loop will not execute. The same is also true for `for (j = 1`.

The problem can be fixed by changing the following:

1. `for (i = 0`
2. `for (j = 0`